# "custom.css" does not overide "bootstrap.min.css"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pulling my hair out trying to understand why `css/custom.css` does not overide `css/bootstrap.min.css`.

I have in the `<head>`

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylsheet">
```

In `css/custom.css` I have, as an example

```
body {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

But my background does not turn yellow. It remains white.

**edit**

If I comment out the Boostrap css link, the page collapses into an HTML skeleton, but the background still does not turn yellow.

Comment: if you remove the bootstrap css link, do you get a yellow background? Perhaps your custom.css has a problem

Comment: You may be on to something; If I comment out the boostrap css link, the background does not in fact turn yellow.

Comment: Well there you go :)

Comment: Thanks :) what do I now? The file should work shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

try being more specific:

```
body {
background-color:yellow;
}
```

also check if `css/custom.css` gets loaded in your header after  `css/bootstrap.min.css` correctly

Comment: Taken into consideration, but no results

Comment: also look if background image is set , I know there are some issues for a background color to override an img..

Comment: There is no image. The override doesn't work for any examples (that I can think of).

Comment: check developer tool maybe you have container overlaying on body

Comment: what is the developer tool?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the bootsrap css link, saving the html file, and re-inserting the boostrap css link worked like magic. I have no idea why. I am working in Ubuntu. Maybe that is to take into consideration.